# Displaying Custom 404 Error Page in Commerce Cloud

Tags: error, commerce-cloud, cloud

I've been trying to display a Custom 404 page in Commerce Cloud. The page has been created in the Cartridge because it was easier/faster doing it that way than having to recreate a full html page, zip, and upload.

Anytime I test it, the default Commerce Cloud 404 error page displays.

How can I point to/reference the custom 404 error page so that it can display ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 page is diplayed when the `Home-ErrorNotFound` pipeline is called, so you would need to override the `Home.js` controller and the corresponding template (or just the template depending your setup) in your cartridge.

```
server.get('ErrorNotFound', function (req, res, next) {
  res.setStatusCode(404);
  res.render('error/notFound');
  next();
});
```

Additionally to that, you can upload custom storefront error pages which also inlcude a `URL not found` case, see [Custom Storefront Error Pages](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FSiteDevelopment%2FCustomErrorPages.html&resultof=%22%65%72%72%6f%72%22%20%22%70%61%67%65%22%20%22%70%61%67%22%20)

Comment: I used the above by overriding the Home.js controller and the corresponding template and it worked like magic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're referring to is the 'Custom Error Page' for *URL Error* conditions which is defined in a file called: `url_error.html` within the Zip file that is uploaded to Business Manager and then stored on the POD's web adapter server.

There is a significant different between *that* 404 page and the one described by empiric in his answer. The condition when `url_error` would be shown is a URL that *cannot be routed to a Site* in SFCC. The Web Adapter is unable to determine *which* site to route that URL to or the URL is malformed in some way resulting in a failure to determine which Site it is associated with.

The `ErrorNotFound` controller method controls the rendered content when the Web Adapter *was* able to route the request to a Site, but the page didn't exist in that site. When you return a 404 response code from this controller, you will not be able to include any remote includes in that page's content. Furthermore you cannot use Slots either as they are also remote includes. To get around this we often return a 410 status code instead which allows us to perform remote includes.